# Surgimento da Div animado

Tags: html, css, script

Eu tenho uma Div, estou construindo um Menu Personalizado, no estilo Responsivo.
Gostaria de fazer com que ela surgisse um com animação, vindo do lado Esquerdo.
A Div contém os links do Menu e um botão para fechar dentro.
Vejam o código que eu tenho até agora:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://hugovales.esy.es/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('.open-menu').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var url = $(this).attr('href')
   $('#menu').fadeIn(500); 
  });
  
  
  $('#menu, .close-menu').click(function(e){
   if( e.target !== this ) 
          return;
   $('#menu').fadeOut(500); 
  });
  
  
  
    });
</script>
```

```html
<div id="menu" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; display:none; -webkit-touch-callout: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none;">
<div id="mymenu" style="background-color: #fff; height: 100%; width: 20%; position: fixed; left: 0pt; top: 0pt; box-shadow: 10px -9px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);"><img class="close-menu" style="margin-left: 220px; margin-top: 10px;" src="http://hugovales.esy.es/css-alternative/bb083d7b27e4e2fd8e7f50c623582d10_30x40.png"></div></div>
<div class="open-menu">Open Menu</div>
```

Esse menu pode ser visto aqui, [no meu site.](http://hugovales.esy.es/)

Vocês podem ver ali o texto "Open Menu" (No Cabeçalho, Perto do Ícone do Facebook)

O Que eu quero é que ele surja com uma animação, pelo lado esquerdo.
Tem como fazer essa Div (mymenu) aparecer assim? (Seja lá com CSS ou algum Script)

Obrigado á quem se dispôr á responder. Ajuda Muito Mesmo!

Answer (score 1):

Use a propriedade `Transition`:

```
<div id="mymenu" style="transition: 2s ...">
```

`2s` é o tanto de segundos que durará a animação. Você também pode especificar a transition para uma propriedade específica:

```
transition: margin 2s;
```

Comment: Isso significa que a Div vem da esqueda como eu queria?

Comment: A propriedade transition anima "qualquer coisa" do html. Sim, também se aplica a esse caso.

Comment: Eu Não consegui moço.

Answer (score 0):

Para animar o menu no momento que o evento de click é acionado, você pode utilizar o método `.animate` do jQuery.

Para saber mais recomendo que você veja a documentação:
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Exemplos: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp